# How to render a page from an AJAX POST request?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I make a POST AJAX request:

```
firebaseAUTH.currentUser.getToken(true).then(function(idToken) {
    $.ajax({
        // Send token to your backend via HTTPS (JWT)
        url: '/auth',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {token: idToken},
        success: function (response) {
            var userID = response.userID
            firebaseDB.ref('/users/' + userID)
                .once('value')
                .then(function(snapshot) {
                    $.post('/members-area/' + userID, snapshot.val(), function(data, status) {

                    });
                });
        }
    });
});
```

My handler:

```
app.use('/members-area/', function(req,res,next) {
  console.log(req.body) //works well and gives object
  res.render('members-area', { Snapshot: req.body})
})
```

However, it does not render the page. Why is that and how can I achieve that?

I can't move that function call outside of the success attribute of the AJAX call, as then the decoded userID variable would not be available.

Comment: An AJAX response should return *data* which is rendered by client-side Javascript. Otherwise there isn't much point to doing an AJAX request over a traditional POST form submit.

Comment: How would it be correct to do then? I can't move it outside the success function, as then I wouldn't have access to the userID variable.